# Range of a piecewise function

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Apologies, this is a simple question but I seem to have some sort of brain freeze. I'm looking for the range of this piecewise function:

$$f(x)=\begin{cases}x+9&\text{ if } x<-3\\
-2x&\text{ if }-3\leq x\leq 3\\
-6&\text{ if }x>3\end{cases} $$

The domain is $\mathbb{R}$ and is the range $[-6,6]$ or $(-\infty, -6]$?

Thanks

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: It's neither of those, I don't think.

Comment: Try finding $f(-3)$

Comment: Did you attempt to draw the graph? The graph consists of portions of three straight lines. When you sketch the graph the answer is obvious.

Comment: Thank you John Wayland Bales, I did. I know it is silly but I am finding it difficult for some reason today.

Comment: Note that since you have two options for an answer you can rule out the first option if you can find a value of $x$ for which $f(x)$ lies outside the range $[-6,6]$. For example, when $x=-19$ we get $f(-19)=-19+9=-10$. We have to use the $x+9$ part of the definition since $-19<-3$. Since $-10$ does not lie in the interval $[-6,6]$ the correct option must be $[-\infty,6]$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x<-3$ we get $f(x)<6$ and $f(-3)= -2(-3) =6$ so $(-\infty,6]\subseteq Range(f)$.

We get nothing new from other parts of function. So $Range(f)= (-\infty,6]$ since it is continuous on $(-\infty ,-3]$.

Comment: Yes ok thank you very much, I see that now, don't know what I was thinking thank you.